# Accessing audio and image from xcassets with same name

Tags: ios, xcode10

I have to assets one is image and another is audio file. Both have the same name.

I created to assets catalogs:

```
Audio.xcassets
Images.xcassets
```

Xcode can find the images assets but not the audio files. There is a way to have the two different assets with the same name?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: check if the Audio.xcassets target is set to your target

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi, Yes, the audio target is set to my target